# Imprimir permisos de escritura y ejecución de manera recursiva

Tags: powershell

Estoy tratando de evaluar los permisos de archivos donde se tenga el permiso de escritura o el de ejecución. El problema lo obtengo al realizar esto de manera recursiva, ya que de esa manera no se imprime la tabla con cada uno de los archivos encontrados. El otro problema que obtengo es como poder filtrar entre los que solo sean de ejecución o escritura.

## Script:

```
    function checkFilePerms {
        Write-Host "`n[*]Looking for perms on files . . ." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    
        try{
            #$filePerms = (get-acl "C:\").access | Select-Object @{Label="User/Group";Expression={$_.IdentityReference}}, @{Label="Perms";Expression={$_.FileSystemRights}}, @{Label="Access";Expression={$_.AccessControlType}}| Format-Table -auto | Out-String
            $path = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Write-Host $path
            ForEach ($directory in $path) {
                try{
                    $filePerms = (get-acl $directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).access | Select-Object @{Label="User/Group";Expression={$_.IdentityReference}}, @{Label="Perms";Expression={$_.FileSystemRights}}, @{Label="Access";Expression={$_.AccessControlType}}| Format-Table -auto
                
                    Write-Host $filePerms -ForegroundColor Green
                }
                catch{
                    Write-Host (-join("Error while enumerating perms on ", $directory.Fullname)) -ForegroundColor Red
                }
            }

            
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host "Error while enumerating perms on files" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
```